# Python - Pandas, Create csv without column number

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i try to create a csv file with python
but if i write a value into the file it works but the first entry is a 0.

```
class csv_file:
def __init__(self, filename, path):
    self.filename = filename
    self.path = path

def read_temp(self):
    self.temp = int(input('enter the value'))
    return self.temp

def open_file(self):
    self.Data = [self.temp]
    self.entry = pandas.DataFrame(self.Data)
    print(self.temp)
    print(self.Data)
    print(self.entry)
    self.entry.to_csv(desktop_path+"/"+self.filename,mode='a', index=False, sep=' ')
```

[image]

how could i insert values without the 0 ?

thx a lot

Comment: use `header=False` as argument of `to_csv`

Comment: Read the params in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html): use `header=False`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10, 13, 24])
print(df)
print(df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)

# Output
    0
0  10
1  13
2  24


# Content of csv file
10
13
24
```

Comment: of course :D
greate thx